# Using TOAD's SQL Tracker with Visual Studio and IIS

Tags: visual-studio-2010, toad

My current project uses Visual Studio 2010 and TOAD.  It is an MVC project with Oracle 11g.  I can get the SQL I am producing with logging and or debugging, however, since I already have a TOAD license I would love to be able to use the Tools for Oracle product, SQL Tracker to get the SQL in runtime without having to use logging or break points.

I assume I need to use the devenv.exe (VS executable) process but I cannot get it to add to the SQL Tracker tool.  I get the error:

```
cannot create process; error=[740] (the requested operation requires elevation.)
```

Any google search says it has to do with running as admin.  I have tried to include the Command-line argument of "RUNAS Administrator" (as well as a variety of other options) with no luck.

**Update:**

I am now able to Start monitoring the devenv.exe process.  In order to do this I needed to run the applications as administrator before I even started SQL Tracker.  However, no output is being captured.

I think I probably need to monitor the IIS process instead (w3wp.exe).  When I click to start monitoring this process I now get the error:

```
Failed to create remote thread; error=8 (Not enough storage is available to process this command.)
```

I believe monitoring IIS is the correct approach, however, this error is now holding me up.  Again google is not helping and I am running everything as Administrator.

Answer (score 0):

Root cause could be many reasons but one thing that I suspect is caching on IIS. You can start from looking there.

Here are few things that you can try out.

http://forums.iis.net/t/1150494.aspx?w3wp+exe+memory+usage+is+out+of+control

Answer (score 0):

Running Studio as admin will not necessarily run your project as admin too, imagine the security hole. I am fairly confident you can make your project run as administrator by modifying the manifest. There is an article on here at [Forcing an application to Admin from config file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14800089/forcing-an-application-to-admin-from-config-file) but no one ever confirmed whether the answer was right or not, but that does not mean its not. I have noticed on a number of occasions a C# answer gets preference over a VB.NET one on stackoverflow.