# Forcing an application to Admin from config file

Tags: c#, elevated-privileges

Is there a way I can add a setting in the configuration file so that that application will always start as admin?
Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 5):

Not from the config file, but in the .manifest.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<assembly xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1" manifestVersion="1.0">
    <trustInfo xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v3">
        <security>
            <requestedPrivileges>
                <requestedExecutionLevel level="requireAdministrator" uiAccess="false"/>
            </requestedPrivileges>
        </security>
    </trustInfo>
</assembly>
```

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/nikhiln/archive/2007/04/19/embed-a-manifest-to-make-an-application-elevate-in-vista.aspx

Comment: Thanks so much. That works great. I added a manifest file to visual studio but now the application always requires admin privileges when it starts, even if I remove the manifest file from the installation folder. How can I make the application start as admin only if the manifest file is present in the folder?

Comment: Not sure if it's cached or something.  You have a mainfest alongside the .exe, not embedded, right?

Comment: Thanks for your reply Mark. What I did was just copying the manifest in the same folder I put the exe file. I'm not sure if that's the proper way to do it. The file was named myfile.exe.manifest

Comment: That's how it should work; I'm surprised that removing it would still result in UAC requests.  I tried finding any documentation on whether Windows caches this, but couldn't find any.

Comment: Thanks. My problem is that when I copy the file in the installation folder, the application still runs as non admin. I'll probably create a second executable that automatically runs as admin.

Comment: Manifests can be embedded. Starting from Windows Vista, embedded manifests have precedence over external manifests, i.e. a separate manifest file (see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17853304/manifest-embedded-and-external-which-has-priority-can-one-override-other).