# Manifest embedded and external - which has priority? Can one override other?

Tags: windows, manifest

When an executable has an embedded manifest and also a corresponding `.manifest` file, which manifest has priority? Is only one loaded? Can one override the other?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I just google it on
[CSI Windows](http://csi-windows.com/blog/all/27-csi-news-general/145-how-can-i-uac-prompt-thee-let-me-count-the-ways)

> **External Manifest:**
>   Precedence Level: 1 (lowest)
>
> **Internal Manifest:**
>   Precedence Level: 2 (*overrides external manifest*)

Comment: Also -- 
`In XP, external manifests have priority and over embedded manifests. In Vista and beyond, embedded manifests have priority over external manifests. For example, if you have an embedded manifest and and external manifest for an application – On XP, the external one will be used; on Vista and later, the embedded one will be used.`  ( http://blogs.msdn.com/b/patricka/archive/2009/12/09/answers-to-several-application-manifest-mysteries-and-questions.aspx )