# Request UAC in visual basic

Tags: vb.net, installation, uac

I am making an installer in visual basic. Basicly, it is a windows form application that installs another program. Well.. I want when the user runs the installer it will show a UAC reqest.Is it possible? Thank's for help.

Comment: Yes, add a reqwuest in your app manifest: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14800089/forcing-an-application-to-admin-from-config-file

Answer (score 0):

For everyone who wants to add uac in his/her application check this : 
[Forcing an application to Admin from config file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14800089/forcing-an-application-to-admin-from-config-file)